# Maximal ideal and invertible element

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I must be prove the following result: Let $R$ a commutative ring with unity, then
\begin{equation}
\bigg (a\in R\;\text{is invertible}\bigg) \Longleftrightarrow \bigg(a\in I,\text{when}\;I\subseteq R\;\text{is not maximal}\bigg).
\end{equation}

**My attempt:** ($\Rightarrow$) Let $a\in R$ invertible, then $R=(a)$. Indeed, if it were not $1\notin(a)$, then $a$ would not be invertible. Therefore $R=(a)$, then $a\in(a)$ which is not maximal. (Correct?)

$(\Leftarrow)$ For this implication I know I must use the Krull-Zorn Lemma, which states that every proper ideal of $R$ is contained in a maximal ideal. 
Could someone help me complete the proof? Thanks!

Comment: For $1^{st}$ part: If $a\in R$ is invertible  and $a\in I$ then $1\in I\implies I=R$ is not maximal.

Comment: Thanks for your anser, if $a\in I$, then $a^{-1}\in I$?

Comment: Since $I$ is an ideal so we have for $a\in I$ and $r\in R\implies ar\in I$. So take $a^{-1}=r$.

Comment: Ok! Sorry! Could you help me too for the second implication?

Comment: Is "$a\in I$, when $I\subseteq R$ is not maximal" supposed to mean "$a$ is not contained in any maximal ideal?"

Comment: @JackJ.: if "$a$  is not contained in any maximal ideal " then $a\in I=R \implies 1\in I\implies \:\exists\:b\in R \::ab=1\in I$.

Comment: I'm not understanding anything, sorry

Comment: So, if $a\in I\subseteq R$, where $I$ is not maximal, then or $I=R$, then $a$ is invertible, or $I\subset R$, then exist $J$ maximal such that $a\in I\subset J$, then $a\in J$ absurd! Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof for $(\Rightarrow)$ is correct. For the implication $(\Leftarrow)$, suppose that for every ideal $I$ of $R$, if $a \in I$ then $I$ is not maximal. Now, if $a$ is not invertible then the ideal generated by $a$ is a proper ideal of $R$ and hence, by Krull-Zorn Lemma, we have that $(a) \subseteq \mathfrak{m} $ for some maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $R$ which contradicts our hypothesis thus, $a$ is invetrible.